# Enable Email Notifications for Gravity Forms Product Add-ons Plugin

Tags: forms, gravity

I am trying to enable email notifications for Gravity Forms Product Add-ons Plugin but cannot seem to get it working.

I have tried changing true to false on the line below but it does not seem to work, anybody got a workaround for this?

```
function disable_notifications( $disabled, $form, $lead )
{
  return true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to enable notifications, I actually got it working with the above line, just needed to clear all caches...

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the notification from the Notifications page for any Gravity Form you've integrated with the GF Product Add-ons plugin. If you want to "abort" all GF notifications, you can use the [gform_pre_send_email](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_pre_send_email/#1-abort-emails).